# Create Alias of Mounted Volume in User Home with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, alias, volumes

On Mac OS 10.10, I'm trying to create an alias of a mounted volume and put the alias in the user's home folder so this can later be put into the dock. The volume is an SMB share called satffdata$ (it's a hidden Windows share, hence the $ at the end). I've tried different variants of the paths, such as explicitly defining it and using the built in alias's but to no avail.

Please see code below and then output. The error code I'm getting and what I've read suggest that the problem could be it's seeing the paths as strings, however I can't explicitly define the startup disk name or the user profile as these may be different at the time the script is automatically run by our Casper Suite system.

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate

    try
        display dialog "Setting your StaffData$ (P Drive) Shortcut. Press OK to continue."
        mount volume "smb://servername/staffdata$"
        set staffData to POSIX path of "/Volumes/staffdata$"
        set homeDir to POSIX path of (path to home folder)
        display dialog staffData
        display dialog homeDir
        make new alias to staffData at homeDir
        set name of result to "staffdata$"

    end try
end tell
```

Output is as follows:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    display dialog "Setting your StaffData$ (P Drive) Shortcut. Press OK to continue."
        --> {button returned:"OK"}
    mount volume "smb://servername/staffdata$"
        --> error number -10004
end tell
tell application "Script Editor"
    mount volume "smb://servername/staffdata$"
        --> file "staffdata$:"
end tell
tell application "Finder"
    display dialog "/Volumes/staffdata$"
        --> {button returned:"OK"}
    display dialog "/"
        --> {button returned:"OK"}
    make new alias to "/Volumes/staffdata$" at "/"
        --> error number -10000
end tell
```

If you've got any questions, I'll respond as soon as I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem of the script is, the Finder does not accept POSIX paths.

The dictionary of the Finder has a property `home` representing the home folder and `disk` objects can easily specified by name

Try this

```
display dialog "Setting your StaffData$ (P Drive) Shortcut. Press OK to continue."
try
    set volumeName to "staffdata$"
    mount volume "smb://servername/" & volumeName
    tell application "Finder"
        if not (exists alias file volumeName of home) then
            make new alias file to disk volumeName at home
            set name of result to volumeName
        end if
    end tell
on error e
    display dialog e
end try
```